# How to visualize the region $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma_0(4)$ and its cusps?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, modular-forms

In number theory we learn that $\theta(z) = \sum q^{n^2}$ is a modular form with respect to $\Gamma = \Gamma_0(4)$.  This boils down to two properties:

- $\theta(z)= \theta(z+1)$ this shift symmetry is pretty clear since perfect square are integers
- $\theta(- \frac{1}{4z}) = \sqrt{\frac{2z}{i}}\,\theta(z)$ this follows from Poisson summation, making it no less mysterious.

$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi n^2 t}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi n^2 / t}$$

I am often drawn to speculate that $\pi\,n^2$ is the area of a circle. In any case the two transformations generate a group:

- $\langle z \mapsto z+1 ,z \mapsto -\frac{1}{4z}\rangle = \Gamma_0(4)$ it can also be written as a matrix group:

$$ \left\langle \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array} \right), \left(\begin{array}{rc} 0 & 1 \\ -4 & 0\end{array} \right) \right\rangle$$

I also read that $\theta(z)$ is a "cusp" form meaning it vanishes at the cusps of $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma_0(4)$ but I have trouble since I don't know what this region looks like or why $\theta(z) = 0$ at these "corners".

---

[Show the Dedekind $\eta(\tau)$ function is a modular form of weight $\frac{1}{2}$ for $\Gamma_0(6)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322233/show-the-dedekind-eta-tau-function-is-a-modular-form-of-weight-frac12)

Comment: The definition of your $\theta$ misses a sum I think.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288478/modular-forms-find-a-set-of-representatives-for-the-cusps-of-gamma-04?rq=1

Comment: umm.. usually $\Gamma_0(4)$ is a subgroup of $\Gamma$ and  $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $4$ and certainly can't belong in that group. Would you care to clarify your definitions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Gamma_0(4)\backslash\mathbb{H}$ is a Riemann surface of genus zero with three cusps. The cusps can essentially be thought of as punctures, hence $\Gamma_0(4)\backslash\mathbb{H}$ looks like a sphere with three punctures.